# Extracted music from swf (game) using swfextract but cannot convert/playback it. ADPCM

Tags: audio, flash

```
$ swfextract spewer.swf
```

prints:

```
[-s] 25 Sounds: ID(s) 1, 873-896
```

so I run:

```
$ swfextract -s 873-896 spewer.swf 
Sound is ADPCM, format: 22050 samples/sec, 16 bit, mono
(…and so on…)
Sound is ADPCM, format: 22050 samples/sec, 16 bit, mono
```

And got file named output.adpcm
But sox couldn't convert it to mp3. How can I convert it to mp3/wav or any other «playable» format?

Comment: Try opening it in Audacity (e.g. import as raw).

Answer (score 0):

there is this program adpcm_swf2raw from https://github.com/alexgirao/adpcm_swf that can do exactly what you want, you just need to go like this:

```
$ swfextract -s 0883 -o 0883.adpcm Spewer.swf
```

Sound is ADPCM, format: 22050 samples/sec, 16 bit, mono

```
$ adpcm_swf2raw -i 0883.adpcm -o 0883.raw

$ sox --rate 22050 --channels 1 --bits 16 --encoding signed-integer --endian little --type raw 0883.raw 0883.wav

$ play 0883.wav
```

enjoy!